# Trying to code a function which takes a scriptblock with params and argument list, edits that scriptblock and then runs invoke-command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, scriptblock

I am editing a function which it will invoke a command directly on the VM. The issue I keep running into is if someone passes a function declaration as a scriptblock, I get and error when calling create, because `params()` is not at the top of the scriptblock.

Trying to figure out how I can still `set-fulllanguage` first then execute a function with params.

```
function Invoke-DirectOnVM
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [CloudEngine.Configurations.EceInterfaceParameters]
    $Parameters,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String[]]$VMNames,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [Object]$VMCredential,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock,

    [Object[]]$ArgumentList = $null
)
{
    Invoke-Command -VMName $localVMs -Credential $using:VMCredential -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create($("Import-Module OpenUpSession; Set-FullLanguage; `r`n" + $using:ScriptBlock)))
}
```

Comment: Don't force the scriptblock... `-ScriptBlock {Import-Module OpenUpSession; Set-FullLanguage; $using:ScriptBlock.Invoke($using:ArgumentList)}`

Comment: Tried this out. Got the Error:
+ ... -FullLanguage; $using:scriptBlock.Invoke($using:argumentList)} -Argum ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expression is not allowed in a Using expression.

Comment: You didn't use what I put, I can see `} -Argum` in your error, but that is not in either your code, or my code. Please make the code you post an accurate representation of the code you're working with.

Comment: Fair enough. I removed the bit of code but the result is the same. Error seems to be with $using:ScriptBlock and .Invoke

Comment: That can be fixed... `-ScriptBlock {Param($ScriptBlock,$ArgumentList);Import-Module OpenUpSession; Set-FullLanguage; $ScriptBlock.Invoke($ArgumentList)} -ArgumentList $ScriptBlock, $ArgumentList`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$using:` from the scriptblock and it should work properly. I took the liberty of cleaning up the code a bit. The result looks like:

```
function Invoke-DirectOnVM
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [CloudEngine.Configurations.EceInterfaceParameters]
            $Parameters,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String[]]
            $VMNames,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
            $VMCredential,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ScriptBlock]
            $ScriptBlock,

        [Parameter()]
        [Object[]]
            $ArgumentList = $null
    )

    $PSBoundParameters.Remove("ScriptBlock")

    Invoke-Command @PSBoundParameters -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create( "Import-Module OpenUpSession; Set-FullLanguage; `r`n" + $ScriptBlock ))
}
```